# Android - service keep alive

Tags: android, service

have a problem  with a system. I have running service, which is constantly checking the position and counting the distance and time since user start it. But after 20-25 minutes and many interactions with other applications service is being killed.

How I can prevent it?

I'm thinking to add second service which will keep my alive.

Comment: You should try , service with Alarm Manager, at a particular timer interval restart the service with Alarm Manager, it works like charm

Comment: How I can do that? Can you provide any small example? And post it as an answer that I can up vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1, minimize your service's memory usage

## 2, make you service foreground, for example in the service's onCreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
     super.onCreate();
    
     Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon_app_small, getText(R.string.app_name),System.currentTimeMillis());
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, [yourService].class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
     notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, [name string], [notification msg string], pendingIntent);
     startForeground(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work for you, but this is how i implemented it:

In my case I needed a service to keep running in the background every X minutes, and whenever it is shutdown (whether due to memory usage or main activity going to background and Android cleaning it up) it would be re-triggered again when the next time interval is reached. I had the following components and workflow:

1. Activity A. Main activity, the starting point of my application.
2. Service S. Service which I want to run in the background, do whatever it needs to do,
   shutdown after completion, and start again after every X minutes.

Activity onCreate method would create a **PendingIntent**, passing it itself and the service S, as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create an IntentSender that will launch our service, to be scheduled
    // with the alarm manager.
    periodicIntentSender = PendingIntent.getService(
              ActivityX.this, 0, new Intent(ActivityX.this, ServiceS.class), 0);
```

In my activity, I have an **AlarmManager** implemented which will take the "**periodicIntentSender**" (defined above) as an argument and based on user preferences (connection_Interval) sends the intent:

```
// Schedule the alarm to start
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(
  AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, connection_Interval, periodicIntentSender);
```

AlarmManager will make sure that the intent will be sent every X minutes. 
My Service S keeps listening to this Intent and gets wakedup each time such an Intent is sent. As soon as the service is triggered again, its **onHandleIntent** method gets called.

```
public class ServiceS extends IntentService implements LocationListener {
.
.
   /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * 
    * @see android.app.IntentService#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)
   */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      <WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO>
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> But after 20-25 minutes and many interactions with other applications
>   service is being killed.

The most likely it's caused by too much memory usage and then automatic memory manager killed your process or long running operation as meant *@AljoshaBre*.

> How I can prevent it?

So my first idea is to check if your `Service` is running in some life-cycle method for example in `onResume()` and if not, just you should restart your `Service` and execute it again.

Comment: Keeping in service Application instance can causing the problem?

Comment: I think not, as i meant most likely it is caused by too long running operation or your memory manager killed process itself.